# Small doubt in the definition of Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

One of the condition of theorem is $|f_{n}(x)| \leq g(x)$..for all n and for all x. But $f_{n}$ and g are complex valued functions, then how we are comparing the above inequality. I mean number on left is real while on right is complex. I think I am doing some stupid thought but not getting exactly where I am going wrong.

Comment: The context of the LDCT is usually real analysis, not complex analysis.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean. Book says that $f_{n}$ are complex measurable!

Comment: Well, the symbol $\le$ is not defined for complex numbers. Could you please type up the statement of the LDCT *exactly* how your book states it? Which book is it, by the way?

Comment: The wiki statement says that the $f_n$ are complex measurable, but it does not say that about $g.$ You may infer that $g$ is real-valued, simply by virtue of the inequality $|f_n(x)|\le g(x).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g$ is assumed to be non-negative, that is, $g$ is a function with codomain $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: I am reading from rudin but author didn't mention this. Instead he say that g $\in L^{1}(u)$

Comment: How does your text define $L^1(u)?$

Comment: If integral of |f| $< \infty$

Comment: The inequality $|f_n(x)|\le g(x)$ implies EpsilonDelta's claim. The symbol '$\le$' is only defined for real numbers; and the LHS is non-negative, making the RHS non-negative.

Comment: @adrian, that's a way to see it, but I think it is still sloppy on Rudin's part.

Comment: Rudin is nothing if not efficient. You'll be hard-pressed to find any book that gets as much done in such a short number of pages. This sort of thing is commonplace with him. Not sure I'd call it sloppy, though. Euclid is sloppy, at least by modern standards.

Comment: I mean sloppy as in: this can be confusing for the reader.

Comment: Rudin is certainly very effective in rushing the theory, but not so effective in teaching the theory. This is just my humble opinion of course.